# Nested "Let" expressions in Ocaml

Tags: nested, ocaml, currying, lambda-calculus

All:

How can I write the following in the "Curry" syntax:

```
let y = 2 in
let f x = x + y in
let f x = let y = 3 in f y in
f 5
```

I at first tried something like this:

```
(y -> (f -> ((f x -> f 5) (y -> f y) 3)) x + y) 2
```

However this does not seem evaluate properly.

Even better yet would be a Lambda-expression to see binding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let v = e1 in e2` translates to lambda calculus as `(\v.e2)(e1)` (where I use the backslash to denote a lambda). So, your example would be

```
(\y1.(\f1.(\f2.f2 5)(\x2.(\y2.f1(y2))(3)))(\x1.x1+y1))(2)
```

I used alpha conversion to differentiate between variables that otherwise would have the same name. Observe that the `f` in the middle has become `f1`, that is the `f` in `f y` in the third line of your example uses the `f` defined in the second line, not the one which is about to be defined in the third line. In other words, your definition is not recursive; you have used `let`, not `let rec`.

Digression: Translating `let rec` into the lambda calculus requires a fixed point combinator `Y` (or some like technique). `Y` is characterized by the property that `Y(f)` reduces to `f(Y(f))`. Then, `let rec v = e1 in e2` roughly translates to `(\v.e2)(Y(\v.e1))`.

Comment: Wonderful. I am familiar with a-conversion but I didn't assume that OCaml syntax was exactly the same and that those were indeed "different" y's. Also: love the digression.